# <t:inputFileUpload> in a <p:dialog> File Upload throws Null Pointer Exception

Tags: jsf, file-upload, jsf-2, primefaces, tomahawk

I'm using  to display a model which has a containing  and a  to upload a file.

The thing is the upload function bound to  throws a null pointer exception.

```
UploadedFile fileToUpload;
```

Is the managed bean attribute to capture the upload file.

If it helps here is the view code

```
<h:form id="frmUploadFile" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="fontS span4">
                Type<span style="color: red;">*</span>
            </div>
            <div class="span8">
                <h:outputText value=":" style="vertical-align: top; margin-right:5px;" />
                <h:selectOneListbox>
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="XXXXX.txt"/>
                </h:selectOneListbox>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="fontS span4">
                File<span style="color: red;">*</span>
            </div>
            <div class="span8">
                <h:outputText value=":" style="vertical-align: top; margin-right:5px;" />
                <t:inputFileUpload id="fileUpload" style="width: 243px;"
                    required="true" requiredMessage="File is required" accept="text/plain , .txt"
                    value="#{uploadController.fileToUpload}" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="offset9 span3">
                <p:commandButton value="Ok" action="#{uploadController.uploadFile()}" oncomplete="dlgUploadDlg.hide()"/>
                <p:commandButton type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="dlgUploadDlg.hide()"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </h:form>
```

The managed bean is in ViewScope, and the null pointer is thrown at

```
objInStream = fileToUpload.getInputStream();
```

What I need to do is, to read the file to a List. I do not need to save the file in a physical location. I cannot understand why it doesnt work.

I read many Q&A published here but still couldn't find a clue.

Comment: You're sending a PrimeFaces ajax request while not using PrimeFaces own file upload component. Uploading files with ajax requires a whole different approach than submitting regular form parameters. Try adding `ajax="false"` to PrimeFaces command button to exclude it from being the cause. Whether it works depends on rest of the configuration which is not clear based on the information provided so far. But, how exactly is PrimeFaces own `<p:fileUpload>` insufficient for you?

Comment: Thank you BalusC, will check and see. The thing is this project source is a bit old. JSF 2.0 and Primeface 3.5 (according to the libs that I noted).

Comment: Just tried this a while ago @BalusC

    <p:commandButton value="Ok" action="#{bulkPaymentSchedulerController.uploadFile()}"
      ajax="false" oncomplete="dlgPaymentUploadDlg.hide()"/>

I had a SOP print the lines. It works.

I had configured the filters as mentioned in the MyFaces doc related to 
<t:inputFileUpload>. Appreciate the help, 

May the force be with you!!